# how to get response from server and message box in client app

Tags: c#

I have a Windows Forms App which has two fields that accept username and password. It then creates a pipe and sends the values the user entered into the fields as a string to the server application. The server application then processes the message by checking if the username entered exists in a dictionary variable it has and then if the dictionary has the username as a key, it checks the password value stored against that username key and returns a response to the client as follows. If the username does not exist in the dictionary then the response is *an account with that username does not exist*, if the username exists and the password is wrong then it should return this response to the client *either the username or the password you entered is incorrect*, if everything is correct it should return *authenticated* as a response to the client.  The client starts the messaging process by sending the login credentials via a button click, the code that does that is below

```
  using(var pipeServer = new NamedPipeClientStream(".","ServerProgram",PipeDirection.InOut))
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Connecting to the server");
      pipeServer.Connect();
      Console.WriteLine("Connected to server");
      //send the ip and the account name to the server
      var writer = new StreamWriter(pipeServer);
      writer.Write(string.Join("-", new string[] { ip, pass }));
      writer.Flush();
      //create a new stream reader to read response from server
      var reader = new StreamReader(pipeServer); 
      var resp = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
      MessageBox.Show(resp);
```

The code above is erroneous in that it sends a message and tries to read the response immediately which makes the client app unresponsive. How can I start a timer and wait for like four seconds and then read the response from the server and process accordingly? Should I use a class that implements a Timer but accepts a NamedPipeClientStream object as a constructor parameter and then use it to read the response, Thank You.